# Can I replace one of the units in a stackable washer/dryer combo?

Tags: washing-machine

We have two individual units and the washer needs to be replaced but not the dryer.  One appliance store said I have to buy both washer and dryer/two new units.  If the dimensions are the same or as long as the washer is bigger than the dryer, is there a reason I have to buy a new dryer?  Are you able to mix brands or not wise?

Comment: Depends how creative you are. I've done it with a shelf, my parents have done it with a customized bracket. So, it can be done. "You must buy a pair" is pure sales slime, coated in a tasty broth of deliberately not having a standard so they would easily interchange, in the attempt to sell you a dryer you don't need.

Comment: The store was probably unwilling to break up a set they had on hand. Perfectly understandable, however, failing to offer ordering a specific replacement for you is not.

Answer (score 7):

You need a bracket to mount the dryer on the washer. The mounting holes are non-standard, so you'll either need to ensure that the manufacturer(s) make such a bracket, make one yourself (or get it made by someone), or mount a shelf in your closet and slide the dryer on that, or otherwise support the dryer without using the washer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if there are 'stack-able' and not 'stacked' (one unit).

Find the model number under/behind the lid/door and order it's replacement. If you live in the USA, I'd recommend [ABT](http://www.abt.com/help/shipping-and-delivery).

Otherwise, do some homework matching up the old and new installation manuals' mounting specifications (good luck) or be prepared to make field modifications to a mix-matched set.

Answer (score 1):

We stacked a Kenmore Elite dryer on top of a new Samsung washer using 2" wide industrial strength velcro. Fits perfectly with no bracket and it's not going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be electrical.  On some appliances, the washer and dryer are electrically mated, so that both appliances can operate off a single power source, and may also be tied together in other ways, such as a condensing dryer using the washer's drain.

Such units are preferred by builders of large apartments/condos, because of the 6 utilities needed in a laundry room (gas 120V 240V water sewer vent), it can cross off as many as 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to stack non-compatible models of Samsung Washer and Dryer. The washer broke and we brought a new Samsung Washer WF42H5000. Older Samsung dryer model is DV206AES/XAC. As per Samsung the new washer WF42H5000 was stackable only to a relatively new dryer model DV42H5000EW/AC.  But we were not happy to buy a new dryer as old dryer was working good. This is what we did:

1. New Samsung Washer WF42H5000 will be at the surface. Stacked the old dryer on top of it.
2. Used old (which was already existing in the previous set-up) stacking kit. I don't know its name.
3. The handy man bored/drilled new slots in the behind of the washer so that the steel bracket from dryer correctly fitted to the new washer slots. That's it, we were done.
4. The washer runs without any problem, no vibration. It runs normal.
5. Please make sure that both washer and dryer are of same width, in most cases it will be same, say 27 inches.
6. The main problem which we foresaw was how the steel brackets will come into correct slot but that was achieved by the handy man as he bored/drilled suitable slots to the new washer to fit the steel brackets from dryer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just put a LG dryer on a Whirlpool Duet washer we had. I cut a 5/8" thick square piece of plywood sized to the exact size of the washer top, drilled 4 holes to the exact size of the legs on the dryer & adjusted each leg to exact dimension for level, so they would fit down into the holes, to secure it from moving in any direction. I made sure to test fit prior to  mounting the ply on top of the washer with 6 sheetmetal screws at the washers ridged edges, lifted up the dryer & it set right in place perfectly. I also painted the plywood white & it's hardly visible. Just for piece of mind I attached the two together with 4- 1"X 3"X 1/8" aluminum plates 2 @ at each side. It needs to all be plumbed & leveled in the end. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently stacked an old Frigidaire dryer (27 wide x 25 deep) on top of a new LG washer (27 wide x 29 deep).  I cut to size a piece of an old foam camping pad and put it on top of the washer.  Placed the dryer on top and am hoping that gravity and friction will be enough to keep them together.
This combo has been in place for a week with heavy use and the dryer has **not moved** a millimeter.  Granted, the new washer is very smooth during its spin cycle.  The enclosure for the combo is quite tight (getting everything back in place and connected is another story -- thank goodness for my skinny 9-year old).  Anyway, my point is that the only way that the dryer could move and fall off would be in the forward direction.
If any significant movement occurs, I promise to come here and give an update.  If you don't hear from me, assume everything is hunky dory.

Comment: It only takes 1 fall to cause serious damage or hurt someone.  I have had my washer or dryer walk a bit depending on the type of load. They aren't stacked currently.  When they were stacked, they were properly connected.

Answer (score 0):

My question was whether I needed to purchase a new stacking kit when replacing a washer that was already stacked with a dryer.

I asked this question at Best Buy and Sears.  Both said no need to replace the staking kit.

When the delivery came out, they were unable to deliver the washer as the new stacking kit was necessary.  We're now without a washer for 4 more days; and that's if everything goes smoothly.  We need to pick up the stacking kit from Sears.  They wouldn't deliver it with the washer without charging an additional 79.99 for delivery; which was already paid for the washer delivery.

So, as far as I now know, yes you need a new stacking kit even if you already have one in use with a washer and dryer that is stacked.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Home Improvement! This answer could benefit from a bit of cleanup and focus on the answer (I see the answer in the last sentence but it takes a bit of reading to get there). Please consider bolding the relevant part of your answer or adding a TL;DR. You could also edit out some of the background to direct more focus to your answer. Also, please take the [tour] for a lot more information about how to participate in Q&A here.

Comment: It would also be helpful to indicate _why_ a new stacking kit was necessary. Were the old and new component different brands? Were there mounting holes that had "conveniently" been moved in the years between the original purchase and the replacement purchase? Was there something else that required the new bracket? Could the old bracket have been modified by a creative DIYer (i.e. one with a drill to make new holes to line up with the new component)? Something else entirely?

Comment: "*they were unable to deliver the washer as the new stacking kit was necessary.*"  Why? Why did they say that and why, if it was true, was it true?